# Error not defined for displaying error for log in

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, authentication

I am working on a project about blogs and trying to display errors when users log in with the incorrect password and username. I attempted to use the same code that I use in register to log in, but it returned error not defined. I didn't know which code I should change in order to make the code work. A little help is much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

This my index.js

```
const express = require('express')

const app = new express()
const ejs = require('ejs')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const fileUpload = require('express-fileupload')
const newPostController = require('./controllers/newPost')
const homeController = require('./controllers/home')
const storePostController = require('./controllers/storePost')
const getPostController = require('./controllers/getPost')
const validateMiddleWare = require('./middleware/validationMiddleware')
const newUserController = require('./controllers/newUser')
const storeUserController = require('./controllers/storeUser')
const loginController = require('./controllers/login')
const loginUserController = require('./controllers/loginUser')
const expressSession = require('express-session')
const authMiddleware = require('./middleware/authMiddleware')
const redirectIfAuthenticatedMiddleware = require('./middleware/redirectIfAuthenticatedMiddleware')
const logoutController = require('./controllers/logout')
const flash = require('connect-flash')

app.use(fileUpload())

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/my_database',{useNewUrlParser: true})
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))

app.set('view engine', 'ejs')

app.use(express.static('public'))

app.listen(4000, () => {
    console.log('App listening on port 4000 ...')
})

const { error } = require('console')

const customMiddleWare = (req, res, next) => {
    console.log('Custom middleware called')
    next()
}
app.use(customMiddleWare)

app.use(expressSession({
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    secret: 'keyboard cat'
    
    }))

app.use(flash())
    
app.use('/posts/store', validateMiddleWare)

global.loggedIn = null
app.use("*", (req, res, next) => {
    loggedIn = req.session.userId
    next()
});

app.get('/', homeController)

/*display each blog in specific url*/
app.get('/post/:id', getPostController)

app.get('/posts/new',authMiddleware, newPostController)

app.post('/posts/store', authMiddleware, storePostController)

app.get('/auth/register', redirectIfAuthenticatedMiddleware, newUserController)

app.post('/users/register', redirectIfAuthenticatedMiddleware, storeUserController)

app.get('/auth/login', redirectIfAuthenticatedMiddleware, loginController)

app.post('/users/login', redirectIfAuthenticatedMiddleware, loginUserController)

app.get('/auth/logout', logoutController)

app.use((req, res) => res.render('notfound'))
```

This is my login.user js in controller file

```
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt')
const User = require('../models/User')

module.exports = (req, res) =>{
const { username, password } = req.body;

User.findOne({username:username}, (error,user) => {
    if (user){
        bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, (error, same) =>{
            if(same){ 

                req.session.userId = user._id
                res.redirect('/')
            }
            else{
                 const validationErrors = Object.keys(error.errors).map(key => error.errors[key].message)
                 req.flash('validationErrors',validationErrors)
                res.redirect('/auth/login')
            }
        })
    }
    else{
        const validationErrors = Object.keys(error.errors).map(key => error.errors[key].message)
        req.flash('validationErrors',validationErrors)
        res.redirect('/auth/login')
    }
})
}
```

This is my login.ejs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <%- include('layouts/header');-%>

<body>

  <%- include('layouts/navbar');-%>

      <!-- Page Header-->
      <header class="masthead" style="background-image: url('/img/kitty.jpg')">
        <div class="container position-relative px-4 px-lg-5">
            <div class="row gx-4 gx-lg-5 justify-content-center">
                <div class="col-md-10 col-lg-8 col-xl-7">
                    <div class="page-heading">
                        <h1>Login</h1>
                        <span class="subheading"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>

  <!-- Main Content -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-10 mx-auto"> 
      <% if(errors != null && errors.length > 0){ %>
        <ul class="list-group"></ul>
        <% for (var i = 0; i < errors.length; i++) { %>
        <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-danger"><%= errors[i] %></li>
        <% } %>
        </ul>
        <% } %>    
      <form action="/users/login" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="control-group">
          <div class="form-group floating-label-form-group controls">
            <label>Login</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="User Name" id="username" name="username">  
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
          <div class="form-group floating-label-form-group controls">
            <label>Password</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" id="password"
            name="password">             
          </div>
        </div>                   
        <br>          
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >Login</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<hr>

  <%- include('layouts/footer');-%>

  <%- include('layouts/scripts');-%>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I define flash data like this:

```
req.flash('errors', ['User Not Found']);
```

Firstly you need define middleware for get flash data (because you are redirecting)

It must be define before login route

```
  app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.locals.successes = req.flash('successes');
    res.locals.errors = req.flash('errors');
    global.user = req.user || null;
    next();
  });
...
  router.get('/login', AuthenticationController.loginPage);
```

After that you need use on your login view (I am using hbs)

```
{{#each errors}}
<div class="alert alert-left alert-danger d-flex align-items-center gap-2 alert-dismissible fade show mb-3" role="alert">
  <span class="d-flex"><i class="material-symbols-outlined">notifications</i></span>
  <span>{{this}}</span>
  <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"></button>
</div>
{{/each}}
```

Comment: Hi..I try to do as you suggest but I seem cannot solve the problem..It still showing error